# Exception while loading xml file from a web address

Tags: xml, exception, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to load an xml file in powershell. Below is my code snippet

```
$url= "http://mYjenkins:8081/job/Test/config.xml"
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($url)
```

But this code always returning an Error as

```
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine"
At line:1 char:10
+ $doc.Load($url)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I Used the below code also,

```
[xml]$doc = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
```

But this also returning the  same error. Please suggest some solutions to solve this problem

Comment: Is the URL always valid an XML document instead of, say, login form?

Comment: Yes, some times a login form comes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the file straight into a XML document, load it into a variable for further analysis. Without any proxies and authentication, it is very simple like so,

```
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient 
$s = $wc.DownloadString("http://what.ever/doc.xml")
```

With integrated Windows authentication, pass the default credentials like so,

```
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient 
$wc.Credentials = [Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
$s = $wc.DownloadString("http://what.ever/doc.xml")
```

For a proxy that requires authentication, things are slightly more complex like so,

```
$proxy = [Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebProxy()
$proxy.Credentials = [Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials

$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true  
$wc.Proxy.Credentials = $wc.Credentials
$s = $wc.DownloadString("http://what.ever/doc.xml")
```

Now that you've got the XML document in a variable, it should be easy enough to check what's really going on.

Comment: Sorry to say that an other error coming now like `Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."`. I said i am trying to load the config file of a jenkins job. I have an account for this jenkins also. But i can download or load other xml files from this jenkins without any problem except the `config.xml` file

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on the above commented error?

Comment: Does your Jentkins setup support integrated Windows authentication? Does it ask for credentials if you try to open the document with a browser?

Comment: Yes, it will ask for the credentials when open the doc in browser

Comment: @ѕтƒ Jenkins authentication settings should be configured for integrated Windows authentication. As per how to do that, contact the server admin. If that's you, I'm afraid you got to figure out how to do that. After IWA works in browser, WebClient ought to work too.